# Partially update row in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's assume we have the following data.table:

```
> dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
> head(dt)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I would like to update the columns `cyl:wt` of the first row with the vector `vec <- 1:5` such that:

```
> head(dt)
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   1    2   3    4     5 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I tried:

```
dt[1, .SD := vec, .SDcols = cyl:wt]      # fails
dt[1, (.SD) := .(vec), .SDcols = cyl:wt] # fails
```

Comment: You could assign `vec` directly to the columns (without using `.SD`). Something like `cols <- c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt") ; dt[1, (cols) := as.list(vec)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.SD` cannot be used on the `lhs` of `:=` for assigning.  We need a character vector.  Another option is `set`

```
j1 <- which(names(dt) %in% c('cyl', 'wt'))
j2 <- j1[1]:j1[2]
for(j in seq_along(j2)){
   set(dt, i = 1, j = j2[j], value = vec[j])
 }

head(dt)
#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1: 21.0   1    2   3 4.00 5.000 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

NOTE: We have to be careful while updating the values and should check the `class` of the original columns as it can have `numeric/integer` changes